# Bootstrap Form Layout (different order of elements in Mobile and Desktop)

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have the form that has different order of elements in Mobile and Desktop version.

I use Bootstrap and LESS. Is it possible with these tools to acomplish this task?
Maybe JQuery should help?

This is what I have need to have in Mobile and Desktop view.

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Not possible in pure CSS, you will have to use javascript and manually append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question.
For example id for fourth element is #four
we need move this element  when adapt page.
Then we can use this Jquery script:

```
function updateAreaFour() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
  function updateContainer() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
      var buttonArea = $("#four");
      $("#second").append(buttonArea);
    } else {
      $("#four").insertAfter("#three");
    }
  }
  updateContainer();
  $(window).on('resize',function(){
    updateContainer();
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can order them by cols , like this one : this is simple javascript :

```
<script>
    window.onresize = function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 768){
            var a = document.getElementById('a');
            a.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12"><label> name 3:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">';
            document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = '';
        }else{
        var b = document.getElementById('b');
            b.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12"><label> name 3:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">';
            document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

and the html is like this :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
               <label> name1 :</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">   
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
               <label> name 2:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">   
            </div>
            <div id="a">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
               <label> name 4:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">   
            </div>
            <div id="b">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                   <label> name 3:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">   
                </div>
            </div>
```

resize the screen and see the changes !

Comment: But in desktop view 4th element should be in the third column.That's the problem

Comment: what do u mean ? for each input u should use the above html and all things will be ok , so what's wrong ?

Comment: For phones - I have in order from top to bottom - first, second, third, fourth elements. For desktops I will have In first row first, second, third elements.In second row - fourth element. But I need to have for desktops in first row first, second, fourth element, in second row - third element.

Comment: this is possible with javascript or jquery .

Comment: Just newbie in front end development) So add jquery tag, maybe someone can help